# How to include command when executing python entry-point command in AWS Elasticbeanstalk?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying my flask application in AWS Elasticbeanstalk and I want to add a command for running datadog tracing when executing entry-point command. How can I do that?

This is the entry-point command to start my flask app in local machine:

```
python3 application.py
```

This is how to add a command before that entry-point command (using datadog as example):

```
ddtrace-run python3 application.py
```

How to do the same in AWS elasticbeanstalk? Seems like beanstalk is using apache + mod_wsgi to run python-flask application but I am not sure how to add a command before the entry-point command.

Answer (score 0):

You can run datadog tracing on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Flask by configure tracing manually as defined [here](http://pypi.datadoghq.com/trace/docs/web_integrations.html#flask):

```
from ddtrace import patch_all
patch_all()

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'hello world'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```